# What's are some of the strangest ackowledgements you've ever seen in a masters/PhD thesis?

Tags: thesis

Typical "ackowledgements" section in a thesis thank supervisors, collegues, friends, family and/or deity.

There was a recent article on atypical acknowledgements, such as this one below:

[image]

[image]

This got me curious, Hence the question— What are some funny, witty or strange ackowledgements you've ever seen in a thesis?

Have you ever seen something hateful or negative in the ackowledgements section of a thesis?

Comment: I think this is a highly subjective and opinion-prone question with no "correct answer", but there are lots of similar questions on here that you might find interesting, e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95885/do-you-consider-it-as-weird-if-i-thank-the-open-source-community-in-the-acknowle/95955

Comment: The acknowledgments of my master's thesis, written around 25 years ago, contained quite a lot of "colorful" language (to say the least) and stirred a bit of commotion in the graduation board. The president wanted to remove the _cum laude_, but the other members eventually convinced him that I was not such a bad guy, after all. The secretary of the student office who received the copy of the thesis (at the time on paper) later said: "I knew he was up to something, he was grinning while handing in the copy!".

Comment: Can you please give the reference (or a link) to the paper that discusses unusual acknowledgements.